# How can tabindex be used in a Polymer component that is used multiple times in a page?

Tags: html, dart, tabindex, dart-polymer

Currently I have a polymer element which contains a form with a few different fields. I have a `tabindex` setup on the input elements, however this polymer element is repeated 5 times throughout the page.

When I use tab for navigation, instead of following the tabindex within each component first, it instead goes to `tabindex` 1 for each component. Then all the tabindex 2's, and so forth. Is there any way for the tabindex to be encapsulated with/in the shadow dom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to see a '7.2 Focus Navigation' section in the Shadow DOM spec.
http://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/shadow/#focus-navigation

Tabindex should be *scoped* in each node tree. Google Chrome already supports that.
I've implemented that. :)

- If you find any unexpected behavior in the implementation, please file a bug for Chrome: http://crbug.com/
- If you find an issue for the spec, please file a bug for the spec:  Click a 'file a bug' button displayed at the top-right corner in the Shadow DOM spec.